# Fatal error: Class 'CI_Model' not found in

Tags: codeigniter, fatal-error

My problem is to make super model class with common functions for routines with models(findByPk, FindByAttributes and so on).

For thjs I decided to make new library that extends `CI_Model` class and to extend all models from `MY_Model` class.

So I added `MY_Model` to `$autoload['libraries']` array.

When adding `model` to this array I've got error:

> Unable to load the requested class: Model

But main problem is that on application start I get:

> Fatal error: Class 'CI_Model' not found

`CI_Model` class in `core` folder exist. So please say What maybe the explanation "why I cant extend CI_Model class in my library with MY_Model!"

Comment: show your piece of code please

Comment: are you creating model inside application/core/ folder?

Answer (score 11):

use

```
$autoload['models']
```

for loading models automatically, instead of $autoload['libraries']

Answer (score 0):

Check in

---

- class CI_Model which should be in `../system/core/Model.php`. and your extends model name same as class name.
- create your model in `application\models\your_model.php`.
- `$autoload['model'] = array('your_model');`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's late, but for future readers.

before loading your library in the constructor of the controller class, load any model of your creation then load the library that extends the CI_model. 
check the below:

```
    public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('User_model');
    $this->load->helper('url_helper');
    $this->load->library('session');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->library('admin_auth');
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    }
```

as you see, that I have loaded the User_model then the admin_auth. 
hope this helps